# DryIoc, Spring.Net's GetObjectsOfType equivalent?

Tags: spring.net, dryioc

With Spring.Net, it's possible to query all objects of a certain (ancestor) type.

```
        var ctx = ContextRegistry.GetContext();

        var setUsers = ctx.GetObjectsOfType(typeof(ISetUser)).Values.OfType<ISetUser>().ToList();
```

How can this be done with DryIoc?

Comment: How your ISetUser are registered? I assume you've tried ResolveMany already.

Comment: It's not registered, it's just an interface some of my registered/mapped classes implements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The direct answer given sample classes and interfaces would be:

```
public interface IA { }
public interface IB { }
public class AB : IA, IB { }
public class AA : IA { }

[Test]
public void Resolve_all_services_implementing_the_interface()
{
    var container = new Container();
    container.Register<IB, AB>();
    container.Register<AA>();

    // resolve IA's, even if no IA service type was registered
    var aas = container.GetServiceRegistrations()
        .Where(r => typeof(IA).IsAssignableFrom(r.Factory.ImplementationType ?? r.ServiceType))
        .Select(r => (IA)container.Resolve(r.ServiceType))
        .ToList();

    Assert.AreEqual(2, aas.Count);
}
```

If you will want to retrieve some interface, it probably good to register it from the start (plan for it):

```
[Test]
public void Resolve_automatically_registered_interface_services()
{
    var container = new Container();

    // changed to RegisterMany to automatically register implemented interfaces as services
    container.RegisterMany<AB>();
    container.RegisterMany<AA>();

    // simple resolve
    var aas = container.Resolve<IList<IA>>();

    Assert.AreEqual(2, aas.Count);
}
```